# How to prevent automatic superscript when typing caret sign and a number

Tags: lubuntu, keyboard-layout

I am running Lubuntu 17.04 through VirtualBox with a Swedish keyboard layout. Whenever I hit the caret sign (^) followed by a number, it is automatically turned into superscript (²). This is really annoying as I am mostly programming in Sublime, and want to type ^2 explicitly. Is there any way I can prevent this from happening (apart from the obvious "hit space after caret")?

Note that I would like for the caret button to work normally for letters, e.g. for typing 'ê'.

Comment: You can't have both, the PC can't read your mind. With the "dead keys" variant, required for Swedish, you need space after the diacritic whenever you want to type that character alone.

Comment: @MichaelBay So the default interaction of dead keys and numbers in Ubuntu is to create a superscript? Annoying if true, but I'll have to deal with it in that case

Comment: Yes, with "dead keys", "^" followed by a number results in superscripting the number.

Comment: A possible workaround is to add another keyboard layout - Swedish without "dead keys" - and toggle to that one when coding.